# How to mock window.location.href using Jasmine in below scenario

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, window.location

I have below method to test.

```
Item.prototype.getItemID = function() {
  try {

    var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

    var queryString = 'advertid';

    queryString = queryString.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");

    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + queryString + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");

    var results = regex.exec(url);

    if (!results)

      return null;

    if (!results[2])

      return '';

    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));

  } catch (Error) {

    console.log(Error.message);

    return null;

  }

};
```

I have written below Jasmine test code.

```
describe("Call getItemID to get querystring 'AdvertID' value", function() {

  var localContext = {

    "window": {

      location: {

        href: "https://server/sites/abc/def/pages/item.aspx?advertid=2"

      }

    }

  }

  it('Passes - if getItemID returns actual querystring value', function() {

    with(localContext) {

      expect(Item.prototype.getItemID()).toEqual(2);

    }

  });

});
```

Still When the getItemID() gets called the href component gives the current url instead something I want to be.

Please suggest the way to achieve that.Thanks